# Can SQL Server replicate TO SQL Server Compact Edition?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce, replication

Can SQL Server replicate TO SQL Server Compact Edition?

To put this in some relevant context, I'm considering the implications of using SQL Server CE as a near line edge cache instead of querying & caching results from our database.

Answer (score 3):

According to this page [Implementation Replication (SQL Server Compact)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171850.aspx) it would seem possible, to create a replication publication, and a subscriber in SQL Server CE.

Or maybe the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx) is more what you're looking for? See [Database Sync - SQL Server and SQL Compact](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=sync&ReleaseId=3422) for some code samples.

Comment: Definitely the kind of information I was looking for, kudos for posting those links in regards to the Sync framework as this is the type of information I was hoping to gleam by adding the context I did to my question